# Is there a way to show notifications while someone is receiving a phone call?

Tags: ios, iphone

I was wondering if it was possible to send a notification that will show over when a user is receiving a call on the iphone? For example: Present a notification while this screen appears?[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpgBv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not possible . When user receives a call then app goes to inactive state and in inactive state app does dot receive / responds to events.